# Error while importing new projects into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

My eclipse is showing errors on the project folder when I am importing a new project into my eclipse. I am not able to find the reason. Please see the attached image of the error.

[image]

```
[2012-11-12 12:11:32 - ProfilePictureSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2012-11-12 12:11:32 - BooleanOGSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2012-11-12 12:11:32 - Hackbook] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2012-11-12 12:11:32 - Scrumptious] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2012-11-12 12:11:32 - PlacePickerSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2012-11-12 12:11:32 - SessionLoginSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2012-11-12 12:11:32 - FriendPickerSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2012-11-12 12:11:32 - HelloFacebookSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
```

These are the error messages are shown in the console. I have sdk version's 4.1 (API level 16) and 4.0.3 (API level 15) in my eclipse.

Comment: Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
null
Downloading Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
null
Done. Nothing was installed.   Getting this while intalling 2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just right click the project and go to properties -> Android -> and click Project Build Target as Any one of version (Android 2.2 or api level 8)

Hope this will help you .

If you don't have required version installed, Please install it using SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SDK 8 (Android 2.2).

Comment: what is this log ?  [2012-11-12 12:23:33 - SDK Manager] Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3' which was not installed.