# How to install facebook api on emulator in windows 7?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-apps

I'm new for facebook app, so I need help to install the facebook api on android emulator in windows 7.

I have installed the facebook api but I got a library error..

```
[2013-04-02 16:22:35 - HelloFacebookSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
```

in library

....\facebook ?

Comment: check this link please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339428/error-while-importing-new-projects-into-eclipse

Comment: Thanks, but i already that but occurre error compiler, also change compiler take 1.5 the error occur in  <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
                    android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    facebook:preset_size="normal"/>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't install the Facebook API. Neither on a device nor on an emulator.

You make calls to the Facebook API using their SDK for various platforms. In your case, the Facebook Android SDK. This [Facebook Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/android/) is to be integrated in your application that you develop.

However, if you meant install the Facebook App on the emulator (*the OP is mighty unclear*), then you will need to grab the .apk file that is included in the SDK bundle that you can download from the link above. To install that APK, follow these steps:

**Make sure you have the emulator already running.**

1. Download the SDK package.
2. Extract the contents of the zip to a folder.
3. Find the APK file in the extracted folder, in the **bin** folder and rename it to a simple **facebook.apk** file name. Copy this file.
4. Browse to your SDK location on your computer and navigate to the **platform-tools** folder. (We need the *adb* here). Paste the **facebook.apk** file here
5. In an empty area in the folder, with the Shift key pressed, right click and select **Open command Window here** *(make sure you are not doing this on any file or folder)*
6. Now, at the command prompt, type this command:

   adb install facebook.apk

Following the above steps will install the Facebook application on your emulator.

Comment: Tanks Siddharth Lele, that is useful for me

Comment: @EngrWaseemArain: Glad to have helped. :-)

Comment: hmm insha Allah in future. if u have your own blog send me link that.

Comment: i have cover these all setps but error is occure in library file... help for that..tnx in advance

Comment: I have followed exactly the same steps but its giving me error:- Device no found
waiting for device
MY emulator is running.

Comment: @RanjeetSIngh: I'm afraid I have never come across this problem to make definitive suggestions. You could try posting a new question though. Sorry. :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Facebook as part of your application, you can get hold of the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/), which is a Library project to your own. You cannot install Facebook on the Emulator to test, but it will fall back to using the Internet Browser for it's authentication.

The best solution is to test on a real device. You can try using [Samsung Remote Labs](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action#) if you want a real device to test on but don't have one.

Comment: Tanks i have visit that sites

Comment: The correct link for `Samsung Remore Labs:` http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install the Facebook .APK file, you need to perform the following steps:

1) Download the corresponding Facebook .APK file for your Android SDK. Please check this link: [Facebook SDK for Android v4.x Downloads[1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads)

2) If you are on Mac OSX:

Go to Android Studio > Terminal:

```
cd /Users/[your_username]/Library/Android/sdk (or where is the location of the SDK)
```

3)  `./platform-tools/adb install /Users/admin/Downloads/Facebook-some_version.apk`

4) You should see a "Success" message.

Good luck !